# Automating a Web Form Submission

Tags: c#, webforms

I currently have an employee that is performing manual data entry by taking information from an application which was developed in-house and entering it into a vendor based applications form for class signups. This was not a real issue until official launch of the application, which now we already have 1300+ users with data requiring entry. What I want to achieve is an application which takes the user information we have already collected and automatically submits these forms on the vendor website. A web-service or direct access to the vendors database is out of the question (pricing is astronomical), so I really need this form automation to work. Here is the code I currently have, but don't seem to be getting anywhere with it. Any input would really help.

```
public static string HttpPost(string uri, string parameters)
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        string postData = parameters;

        byte[] send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = send.Length;

        Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
        sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
        sout.Flush();
        sout.Close();

        WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
        string returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();

        return null;

        //// parameters: name1=value1&name2=value2  
        //WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        ////string ProxyString = 
        ////   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
        ////   [GetConfigKey("proxy")];
        ////webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy (ProxyString, true);
        ////Commenting out above required change to App.Config
        //webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //webRequest.Method = "POST";
        //byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
        //Stream os = null;
        //try
        //{ // send the Post
        //    webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   //Count bytes to send
        //    os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        //    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         //Send it
        //}
        //catch (WebException ex)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("HttpPost: Request error");
        //    Console.Read();
        //}
        //finally
        //{
        //    if (os != null)
        //    {
        //        os.Close();
        //    }
        //}

        //try
        //{ // get the response
        //    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        //    if (webResponse == null)
        //    { return null; }
        //    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        //    return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        //}
        //catch (WebException ex)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("HttpPost: Response error");
        //    Console.Read();
        //}
        //return null;
    } // end HttpPost
```

Comment: Have you considered using a browser automation tool like selenium? It would allow you to script the user interaction instead of trying to reproduce the exact form data posted to the application.

Comment: It depends on how the vendor website works. There is no generic answer to this question (other than use a tool to help you like Automation Anywhere).

Comment: Can I use Selenium with an existing SQL database? Grab a bunch of records from my database and loop the Selenium script on the same form over and over 1300+ times?

Comment: Yes, absolutely you can.  In fact, it is really easy to do.  Selenium/Web Driver supports ADO.NET and SQL very well.